# How to create my own encryption in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

I need to create a hospital management program in **Python 2.7** for my school project. For that I need to make a **login form** and the **password must not be directly stored in the py file** (for obvious reasons). So what I am thinking is, is there any way using which I can write **my own encryption into a pickled file** and then **unpickle it in my main py file** to use it? And even if I did so, **will it be secure** to some level (keeping in mind that this is just a school project)?

Comment: The proper way to do this is to hash the password and store the hash somewhere.  There are so many resources already on how to do this.

Comment: I am making the project on a single py file. :/ All I can currently know is basic file handling on python.

Comment: Well... Can you write to a file or no?

Comment: I can..........

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Nvm I got what you're saying. Stupid of me not to consider the already existing encryption methods. :'D

Comment: your design is broken, passwords don't go in a file but a datastore - database mostly and python has inbuilt encryption for proven  hasing `sha*`, `md5` etc, use one of those!

Comment: @NoobEditor MD5 and the SHA family are terrible for password hashing, don't recommend them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password needs to be hashed w/ a salt before you store it anywhere.  Keeping it in a pickle file might not be the best idea for production but for a project, it might slide.  There are plenty of encryption modules already built for this purpose like `hashlib`.

Also note you should not use encryption for this.  You should use a hash.  They are distinct and it's important to recognize the differences.

Comment: Storing password in a pickle file is definitely a really bad idea, but, my seniors made their projects with passwords written directly into the main py file and they got 10 on 10 for that (yeah, ik, they just throw away marks). So, I guess storing the password in a pickle file would get their minds blown (sarcasm).